# Is it possible to defeat Jacob in Shattered Eezo?

Tags: mass-effect-3

When on the Silversun Strip (Citadel DLC) there is an option to challenge Jacob in a game of Shattered Eezo. I tried to beat him like 10 times but he always dishes out more damage

Is it possible to defeat him somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is definitely possible to beat Jacob at Shattered Eezo, as shown in this video:

As you can see in the video, charging while he's blocking and then pummeling him while he's stunned is pretty effective.